# Adding columns after comparing values in 2 dataframes with different lengths

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I referenced another stackoverflow, but the value came out weird and I asked again.

like

[compare 2 columns in different dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60586890/compare-2-columns-in-different-dataframes)

```
df1
Name  date
A     2019-01-24
A     2019-02-14
B     2018-05-12
B     2019-07-21
C     2016-04-24
C     2017-09-11
D     2020-11-24
```

```
df2
Name  date2        value
A     2019-01-24  123124
A     2019-02-14  675756
B     2018-05-11  624622
B     2019-07-20  894321
C     2016-04-23  321032190
C     2017-09-11  201389
```

I would like to compare the name and date of df1 and the name and date2 of df2, and if it matches, add value to the new column of df1.

so I using

`df1['new'] = df1.merge(df2, left_on = ['Name','date'], right_on = ['Name','date2'])['value']`

When I applied this to my actual data, I found that strange values(Not what I want, it's weird) were created in the new column. What's wrong with my code?

++++(after answer)

Looking at the answer of @jezrael below, it would be good to apply it according to the characteristics of the data to be applied. In the case of me, there were many duplicate data having the same day, so it could not be applied with simple left_on and right_on.

Comment: How working left join? `df1['new'] = df1.merge(df2, left_on = ['Name','date'], right_on = ['Name','date2'], how='left')['value']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter only necessary columns in `df2` by list and instead `left_on` and `right_on` is used `rename` with `on` parameter for avoid same columns `date` and `date2` in output and also is used `left join`:

```
df = df1.merge(df2[['Name','date2', 'value']].rename(columns={'date2':'date'), 
               on = ['Name','date'], 
               how='left')
```

First solution with `left join`:

```
df1['new'] = df1.merge(df2,
                       left_on=['Name','date'],
                       right_on=['Name','date2'],
                       how='left')['value']
```

I think reason why weird output should be created default index after merge with inner join, so if assign back rows should not match. If use left join then index of left DataFrame in not changed, so assign column working correct.

Comment: It's more intuitive. Thank you.
Like my original code, it is executed without using a left join. Can I know what the problem is?

Comment: @ybin No, the answer is using left join

Comment: The first answer is the solution.(using 'rename')
I think the real df had duplicate data on the same day, so it didn't work. Simple how ='left' means other values are assigned.

It's working fine as it's the first solution you've given me. Thanks!

Comment: @jezrael Can I apply the above logic to comparing 'date + 1day' and 'date2' rather than comparing 'date' and 'date2'? The two of them are strings. Is there any way to compare after adding one day to each date by datetime?..

Comment: @ybin - Maybe the best add new question wirh sample/expected output. I think generally not so easy.