# When comparing columns and adding new columns, the method in date calculation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
df1
Name  date
A     2019-01-24
A     2019-02-13
B     2018-05-12
B     2019-07-21
C     2016-04-24
C     2017-09-11
D     2020-11-24
```

```
df2
Name  date2        value
A     2019-01-24   1
A     2019-02-14   2
B     2018-05-13   3
B     2019-07-20   1
C     2016-04-25   2
C     2017-09-11   3
```

I would like to compare the name and date of df1 and the name and date2 of df2, and if it matches, add value to the new column of df1.

It works well,
[Adding columns after comparing values in 2 dataframes with different lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63028196/adding-columns-after-comparing-values-in-2-dataframes-with-different-lengths)

**What I want to do more is to add value by matching date2 to date, date+1day when comparing date and date2.**

for example,

```
case1. matching True : date - 2019-12-30 : date2 - 2019-12-30
case2. matching True : date - 2019-12-29 : date2 - 2019-12-30
case3. matching False : date - 2019-12-30 : date2 - 2019-12-29
```

In case1 and case2, I want to add a value at df1

so output what I want(apply above logic)

```
df1
Name  date       value
A     2019-01-24 1
A     2019-02-13 2
B     2018-05-12 3
B     2019-07-21 NaN
C     2016-04-24 2
C     2017-09-11 3
D     2020-11-24 NaN
```

Please tell me if there are any parts that are difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with `direction='forward'` and `tolerance=pd.Timedelta(1, 'day')` parameters:

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df2['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date2'])

df = pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values('date'), 
                   df2.rename(columns={'date2':'date'}).sort_values('date'), 
                   on='date', 
                   by='Name', 
                   direction='forward',
                   tolerance=pd.Timedelta(1, 'day')).sort_values(['Name','date'])
print (df)
  Name       date  value
3    A 2019-01-24    1.0
4    A 2019-02-13    2.0
2    B 2018-05-12    3.0
5    B 2019-07-21    NaN
0    C 2016-04-24    2.0
1    C 2017-09-11    3.0
6    D 2020-11-24    NaN
```

Comment: The approach was similar to what I tried, Thanks to you, get to know the new method today!